# Cycle Decomposition of $S_{3}$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose the cycle decomposition $\sigma$ has the following values on ${1,2,3}$,

$\sigma(1)=3$,
$\sigma(2)=2$,
$\sigma(3)=1$.

This cycle decomposition is expressed as $(1 3)$.

Was the third value of $\sigma$ needed to know this cycle decomposition ?

In other words, in order to form a cycle decomposition from any permutation, is it necessary to know the value of that permutation at each and every element of the set being permuted ?

Comment: The function $\sigma$ is not a permutation as you've listed it. For a function to be a permutation of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ (i.e. an element of $S_3$), it must be a $bijective$ function from the set to itself. Did you mean $\sigma(2)=2$?

Comment: Yes you are right that was a mistake.

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set, then every element in $S_X$ is determined uniquely by its action on any $|X|-1$ elements of $X$. In this case, you only need to know what $\sigma$ does to two numbers since the bijectivity determines what is left.

Answer (score 1):

A permutation on $n$ elements, is uniquely determined by is value on $n-1$ of those elements since the there will only be one choice for the value of the $n$-th element.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.